# nested, indented lists with collapsable sections

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

How to create a markdown list with:

- each item being collapsible or not
- items are indented, sub-items are indented 2 times etc ...
- each item "body" containing at each level having the ability to carry regular md, including sub-list, also collapsible.. etc

this [page](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab) presents some solutions, but the most viable one is pure HTML, there no point of MD anymore

Answer (score 1):

We have to play with `details`, `summary`, and ... spaces!
Spaces?? Yes:

- how you indent your whole section body
- where you put your closing `details` tag on the closing line. 
  `</details>` tag must be indented as if it was part of the "body" of your `<detail>`.

Spaces are what makes it work, or not.

Here is a 2-level list with collapsable elements, and sub-elements, with some other regular markdown items.

Example
[rendered in github](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab?permalink_comment_id=4832563#gistcomment-4832563). Works on VS-Code too. Not sure which other engine supports it.

The code:

````
- <details open>
  <summary><a href="#">Section 1 with a link</a></summary>

  - <details>
    <summary><a href="../src/actions/">subsection 2 with a link</a></summary>

    - a list
    - with some stuff

    > and other things

    - [x] like
    - [ ] a task list 

    </details>

  - <details>
    <summary><b>another subsection</a></summary>

    a. with another list
    b. and some other stuff
    d. [and](),
      [more](),
      [classic](),
      [md]
    e. _no need_ __of html__
    </details>

  - <details>
    <summary>last sub-section</a></summary>

    blablabla

    ```rb
    def some_code
      puts "Rails is so cool"
    end
    ```
    </details>

  - a random not collapsable section
    > legacy. Should be restructured.

    ```js
    console.log("look what I found, a new js framework. Still no real alternative to rails though")
    ```

  - <details>
    <summary>and another collapsable section</summary>

    ...
  </details>

- <details>
  <summary>section 2</summary>
      
  some parent content

  and another list

  - <details>
    <summary>section 2.1</summary>

      and some content
    </details>

  - <details>
    <summary>section 2.2</summary>

      and some content
    </details>
  
  - section 2.3
    and some no collapsed content

</details>
````

As you can see, not all engines supports it though... like SO one:

- Section 1 with a link

  - subsection 2 with a link

    - a list
    - with some stuff

    > and other things

    - [x] like
    - [ ] a task list
  - another subsection

    a. with another list
    b. and some other stuff
    d. and,
    more,
    classic,
    [md]
    e. *no need* **of html**
  - last sub-section

    blablabla

    ```rb
    def some_code
      puts "Rails is so cool"
    end
    ```
  - a random not collapsable section

    > legacy. Should be restructured.

    ```js
    console.log("look what I found, a new js framework. Still no real alternative to rails though")
    ```
  - and another collapsable section

    ...
- section 2

  some parent content

  and another list

  - section 2.1

    and some content
  - section 2.2

    and some content
  - section 2.3
    and some no collapsed content